# What are the differences between a windows serial port and a macos serial port using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port, node-serialport

Having an issue communicating with some legacy hardware over a SerialPort RS232 using NodeJS and `"serialport": "^11.0.0"`. I can send data to the device on a windows machine and the legacy device will respond (works fine). If I run the same code on OSX 14.3.1 (m1 2020) the device does not respond or seem to have received any info from the serial port. Any ideas on what the difference between the two platforms might be? Ex: does windows send `\r\n` and darwin sends just `\n` at the os level?